# Get a variable in a function within another function PHP

Tags: php, function, scope, global, var

help me get variable in a function within another function

```
$variable ="alfa";

function foo(){
    $variable ="beta";

    $my_function =    function(){
                         global $variable;
                         return $variable;
                      };

  return $my_function();
}
```

I want the function foo(); print "beta" no "alpha", what's wrong with my code?

```
print foo(); // this print "alpha" and should print "beta"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `use` instead of `global`.

```
$variable ="alfa";

function foo(){
    $variable ="beta";

    $my_function =    function() use ($variable){
                         return $variable;
                      };

  return $my_function();
}
```

You can read more about it [in docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) example #3

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `global $variable;` before assigning `$variable ="beta";`.

If not, you are working in the function scope, not global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the concept of " Scope of the variables "

inside the function `foo()` , you declare the variable $variable, Then in the anonymous function you are accessing the $variable you have declared inside the `foo()`, So if you want to use the global $variable inside the anonymous function, You should make the `global $variable` right after you declare the function `foo()`

```
$variable ="alfa";

function foo(){

global $variable;
$variable ="beta";

$my_function =    function(){
                     global $variable;
                     return $variable;
                  };

  return $my_function();
}
```